# What's a good OSX counterpart for Paint.Net

Tags: macos, software-rec, graphics, paint.net

I love [Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/) on Windows. It's easy, free and gets the job done.

I am looking for something similar for my mac. Preview is able to resize or crop, but sometimes I want to add a shape or combine images. Any ideas?

Comment: Preview has annotation tools too, which I often use to mark up an image like drawing circles and arrows and adding text to draw people's attention to things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the open-source [Paintbrush](http://paintbrush.sourceforge.net/) :

> Paintbrush is a simple paint program
>   for Mac OS X, reminiscent of Microsoft
>   Paint and Apple’s own now-defunct
>   MacPaint. It provides users with a
>   means to make simple images quickly,
>   something that has been noticeably
>   absent from the Mac for years.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/), but maybe It's a bit oversized regarding your needs...

Answer (score 0):

[seashore](http://seashore.sourceforge.net/The_Seashore_Project/About.html) comes to mind - its a cocoa native graphics application with fairly basic features that's based off gimp.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem with seashore is that I am not able to draw a simple shape like a circle or a rectangle. Maybe I am to stupid but neither the documentation nor a google-search revealed to me how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can actually use Paint.NET directly from [within a web browser](https://spoon.net/apps/paintdotnet). As of this writing, this only works on Windows PCs, but support is planned for OSX (see edit below).

**Edit**

If you click the "Run" button from within a browser running on OSX, you get the following message:

> Spoon.net applications currently only launch on Windows PCs and tablets, but **support for Mac is coming soon!**

(Emphasis added).

[image]

Comment: There's nothing on that page about planning OSX support.

Comment: @MichaelKohne Yes there is. See edit.